# Filtering out a '.' from a python dataframe column

Tags: python, string, dataframe

I have a dataframe (df) that contains a column with urls. I want to filter out the values that do not contain a '.'.

I tried this:

```
df = df[~df['Domain'].str.contains('.')]
```

But the results still have some values with a value with no '.' in it. Any advice on how to filter out the specifically '.'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str.contains` treats the input as a regular expression by default.  Try escaping the dot:

```py
df = df[~df['Domain'].str.contains('\.')]
```

Or, turn off the regex input by setting the `regex` flag to false:

```py
df = df[~df['Domain'].str.contains('.', regex=False)]
```